# How to cleanup and manage overlay2 docker?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, overlay

**Description**
Hi, I have a running docker container and my free disk space is infinitely decreases everyday. I have done as below :

**Output of `docker system df`:**

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              1                   1                   2.072GB             0B (0%)
Containers          1                   1                   12.66GB             0B (0%)
Local Volumes       0                   0                   0B                  0B
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

**Output of `du --max-depth=1 -hc /var/lib/docker/overlay2/`:**

```
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l
205M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/693a1e847468523f0d3cd2c90b190b8a23315d4e2581b7ea22785584415f3a9b
281M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/64a9656875d0cf9c420d8dc58757e4f3fc6a7b8b66386c6bffeb2828af76fa1e
148M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f4612f13964de2437a9ebf264d895a0891aa7b4a232f5d20f16131f6eada18c6
85M     /var/lib/docker/overlay2/70b99605aa78817cac753c01cf4132b9698bece265a01751d4da1341d1f13be7
196K    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9bd95ced09a685efd19bdee9efd0a97786ea8dcddeb2982928d3c27db773de59
418M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/970856795dfd597524d694830c85246dd1f5cbc88de7364abe4eaba7ea27bd9e
16K     /var/lib/docker/overlay2/5490f4a0bdb240773b432c5bb593ee7cb195d3afc1a0e566a34ced4056ed98c4
419M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b600a8a8691217a3ce7a1cfa9b6b2784e67ee4f5b8b91e2840657d7f00b0cff9
452M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/89aacbad54ddf4dc1b8e0accbadb9e85a600ff41c1e1cb13ff6b3c470f78b18e
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ee426d956d3f9b4e9729c1e7df27ba3c29e533e2080a0fef71c508ae44e884d-init
16G     /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ee426d956d3f9b4e9729c1e7df27ba3c29e533e2080a0fef71c508ae44e884d
18G     /var/lib/docker/overlay2/
18G     total
```

**Output of `docker system prune --all`:**

```
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all images without at least one container associated to them
  - all build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B
```

**Output of `du -shc /var/lib/docker/overlay2/`:**

```
18G     /var/lib/docker/overlay2/
18G     total
```

How to cleanup and manage overlay2 docker ?

Comment: How much disk space is being used per day? What's the one running container? What files in the overlay folder are increasing in size or being created each day? Are you automatically rotating old container logs? Is the container filesystem being modified within the container with new or larger files?